# Value is not storing in the hidden field after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

In the below code i have a hidden field and a textbox .I want to store the regular expression in the hidden field and compare with my value what i typed in textbox.But when i execute it i can able to print the regular expressions in the hidden field.When i type any value in textnbox a alert msg display undefined or blank alert in hidden field.Pls help me to solve the issue.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                if (FieldTypeInfo == FieldType.TextBox)
                {

                    lblText.Text = FieldLabel;
                    txtreq.Enabled = this.IsMandatory;

                    string strRegularExp = string.Empty;

                    if (ListOfRegularExpression != null)
                    {
                        for (int iRow = 0; iRow < ListOfRegularExpression.Count; iRow++)
                        {
                            strRegularExp += ListOfRegularExpression[iRow].ToString() + "~~";
                            //hidRegExp.Value = strRegularExp;
                            if (iRow == ListOfRegularExpression.Count - 1)
                            {
                                strRegularExp = strRegularExp.TrimEnd("~~".ToCharArray());
                                txtField.Attributes.Add("onblur", "javascript:ValidateRegExp('" + txtField.ToString() + "');");
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    hidRegExp.Value = strRegularExp;

                    lbl.Text =  hidRegExp.Value;
}}

js:


    function ValidateRegExp(txtInput) {

            var hiddenValue = document.getElementById("<%=hidRegExp.ClientID%>").value;
            alert(hiddenValue);
            var mySplitResult = new Array();
            mySplitResult = hiddenValue.split("~~");

            for (i = 0; i < mySplitResult.length; i++) {
                //document.write("<br /> Array[" + i + " ]= " + mySplitResult[i]);
                var re = new RegExp(mySplitResult[i]);
                if (txtInput.match(re)) {
                   // alert("Successful match");
                } else {
                   // alert("No match");
                }

            }}
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hidRegExp" runat="server" ClientIDMode="static" EnableViewState="true" Value="">
    </asp:HiddenField >

          <asp:TextBox ID="txtField" runat="server" CausesValidation="true"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Can you post the actual HTML source and JavaScript that are generated?

Comment: I have already posted the code html and js

Comment: You posted JavaScript with ASP.NET code (`<%=hidRegExp.ClientID%>`) and some ASP.NET controls. Step one to diagnosing your problem is to see the actual HTML and JavaScript that are outputted by ASP.NET to ensure the hidden field is generated properly and there aren't any problems in your JavaScript. Knowing that would help isolate your problem to either the server or the client (right now we can't tell!).